# R syntax problems -- again

Tags: r

The idea here is that I have a CSV file with some whole numbers arranged by date. I want the user to be able to pull down a menu select a type of transaction and make a plot. I rewrote all this in a single file

The issue seems to be in how I have formatted the UIformat to pass the variables to the server. I see random messages like

> ```r
> "Error in sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(uiOutput("regionSel"), selectInput("regionSel",  : 
> argument "mainPanel" is missing
> ```

, with no default

Now it has started to produce output that functions totally unrelated to the code and data I am running.I am increasingly thinking R is possessed by Satan. If any of you help me with this I would greatly appreciate it. I have spent four days on this and nothing works.

```r
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
ui <- fluidPage( 

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Library Statistics"),


    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      

        # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(

            uiOutput("regionSel"),
               selectInput("regionSel", "Type of Questions:", 
               choices=colnames(oboler_data)),
            # ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("myPlot")
    )
)
)
```

## Define server logic required to draw a histogram

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

server
# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
# Define a server for the Shiny app
function(input, output) {

    output$myPlot = renderUI(selectInput("regionSel", "Type of Questions:",
                                            choices=colnames(oboler_data)))
    # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
    output$myPlot = renderPlot({

        # Render a barplot
        ggplot(data = oboler_data, aes(x = "rdate", y = input$regionSel)) +
            geom_point() +
            labs(x = "Date",
                 y = "Total Transactions",
                 title = "Library Data",
                 subtitle = "July 2020-June 2021") 
    })
```

## Run the application

```r
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: do you have any example data so that people can try what you've done?

Comment: This is a csv file with dates in the rows and categories in the columns with whole numbers in the cells.  Not sure how or if stackoverflow lets me upload csv - but if you think a numeric grid with dates in column 1 and categories in column 2 to n you get the idea

Comment: @KarlBridges To share a sample of your data, try `dput(head(oboler_data))` - then edit your question above and copy/paste the results into your question. This would be helpful.  Also, for your `ggplot` statement you might want `aes_string` instead of `aes` if passing character values, such as `input$regionSel`.